# Remove Carriage Return from HTML using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing data from a webpage, and at times the tables have unwanted carriage returns that are giving me problems.  I want to remove the carriage returns but a simple strip() is not working.

I have the following code:

```
html = """
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Commercial, financial and agricultural</td>
<td>
791
</td>
</tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
table = soup.find('table')

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    rowdata = ''
    columns = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in columns:
        cell = ''.join(td.findAll(text=True))
        cell.strip()
        rowdata = rowdata+'|'+cell
    print rowdata
```

The output is:

```
|
Commercial, financial and agricultural|
791
```

I'd like the output to be:
    |Commercial, financial and agricultural|791

Why is the strip function not removing the carriage returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> cell = 'text\n'
>>> cell.strip()
'text'
>>> rowdata = '|' + cell
>>> print rowdata
|text

>>> rowdata = '|' + cell.strip()
>>> print rowdata
|text
```

Strip is removing the returns, but strip returns a value.  It doesn't set cell equal to anything.  Try `rowdata = rowdata + '|' + cell.strip()`.

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb.  Thanks and sorry that was such a dumb mistake.

Comment: Haha don't worry about it, I've made plenty of far worse mistakes in my time.  Glad to help.